# ¿Cómo puedo enviar objetos como parámetro a un hilo desde C#?

Tags: c#, hilos

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
Thread NewThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MethodInThread));
NewThread.Start(MyKitchen);

public static void MethodInThread()
{
    //Mostrar datos de parámetros
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te aconsejo usar hilos parametrizados con la clase `ParameterizedThreadStart`. Te expongo un ejemplo de código:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Kitchen MyKitchen = new Kitchen()
        {
             HasOven = true,
              Size = "36 m2",
        };

        Thread NewThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(MethodInThread));
        NewThread.Start(MyKitchen);

        Console.Read();

        NewThread.Abort();
    }

    public static void MethodInThread(object AnyObject)
    {
        Kitchen ExistingKitchen = AnyObject as Kitchen;

        Console.WriteLine(ExistingKitchen.Size);
        Console.WriteLine(ExistingKitchen.HasOven);
    }
}

public class Kitchen
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public bool HasOven { get; set; }
}
```